# SQL Server AVG function oddity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, excel, weighted-average

I am seeing some odd behavior in SQL Server [AVG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx) calcuation.

On manual calculation, you get `49.277588` 
but SQL Server is reporting that the average is `50.9914` 
as shown below.

***Question:*** Can someone explain the difference and why this is happening?

You can try out the query on AdventureWorks2008 Database with following query

```
select  C.ProductCategoryID, P.ProductSubcategoryID,
        AVG(P.ListPrice) as 'Average',
        MIN(P.ListPrice) as 'Miniumum',
        MAX(P.ListPrice) as 'Maximum'
from    Production.Product P
        join Production.ProductSubcategory S 
            on S.ProductSubcategoryID = P.ProductSubcategoryID
        join Production.ProductCategory C 
            on C.ProductCategoryID = S.ProductCategoryID
where   P.ListPrice <> 0
group by C.ProductCategoryID, P.ProductSubcategoryID
with rollup
```

[image]

**[Update] Answer** 
Here is the result of Weighted Average calculation in Excel
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're doing an average of an average in Excel, which is bad math.

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_an_average_of_averages_accurate

Comment: @David: You are absolutely right.  Upon doing the weighted average calculation, the result came out the same.